# DAG failures are not getting reported

Tags: etl, airflow, airflow-scheduler

We have set up a callback to be triggered on task failures which sends out a slack message. Also, the "email_on_failure" option in enabled to send out emails on failure. However, in many instances, we found that the DAGS was marked as failed in the UI but the error was not reported either by slack or email. Here is how we have setup our DAG:

```
default_args = {
"owner": "Test",
"depends_on_past": True,
"wait_for_downstream": True,
"start_date": datetime(2019, 5, 8),
"email": ["a@a.com"],
"email_on_failure": True,
"email_on_retry": False,
"retries": 1,
'on_failure_callback': task_fail_slack_alert,
"retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5),}

mydag = DAG(dag_id='test_etl',
             default_args=default_args,
             schedule_interval='05 7 * * *',
             max_active_runs=1,
             dagrun_timeout=timedelta(hours=6),
             params={})
```

I am suspecting this happens when the tasks were either completed or in-flight but the DAG timed out. I was wondering if anyone else has seen this issue.

Comment: Have you updated the [smtp] subsection of the airflow.cfg with the correct details for sending the emails ?

Comment: Yes. I have been getting emails for individual task failures. I just don't get an email when the DAG fails due to timeout or some other issues.